# Can't import any library to Android Studio and Gradle Failed to Resolve

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have tried these two libraries in order to make Image Zoomable, but I'm facing the same problem.
This is the error message

> Failed to resolve: com.github.MikeOrtiz:TouchImageView:1.4.1
> Show in Project Structure dialog
> Affected Modules: app

At first, I thought it's maybe because of Jetpack Compose with Java, Because I tried to use TouchImageView Library as I've mentioned here,

> implementation 'com.github.MikeOrtiz:TouchImageView:1.4.1'

for this Library, it was needed to import

> maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

I did import it to build.gradle project, also there was no allproject in that file, then I tried to import it into settings.gradle as well. in short, I just faced the same error message image is shown below

[image: Gradle Warning/error message image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `settings.gradle`

Add this line at bottom: `include ':app',':touchview'`

Add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` to

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I had the same problem. I have also performed the suggested steps below.

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart and so so... I solved this problem by following the steps below:

1. Open your android project.
2. Open the gradle.properties under the Gradle Scripts
3. Add this code
   `android.enableJetifier=true`
4. Add the following code build.gradle(Module:app)
   `implementation 'com.github.chaosleung:pinview:1.3.1'`

After these steps, the problem was solved and I didn't need to add the steps like maven mentioned above.